# ROT13 but with String Method bu i couldnt manageing it

Tags: java, string

Hi im Computer Engineering student and im trying to write a code that take a string from user and encode it with String methode but i don't know where i went wrong.

```
 public static void main(String[]args){
         
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please enter a string to encode: ");
String word=input.next();
System.out.println(f1(i1));


     }
public static String f1(String word, String a) {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        char i1 = word.charAt(i);
        if       ( i1>= 'a' &  i1<= 'm')  i1+= 13;
        else if  ( i1>= 'A' &  i1<= 'M')  i1+= 13;
        else if  ( i1>= 'n' &  i1<= 'z')  i1-= 13;
        else if  ( i1>= 'N' &  i1<= 'Z')  i1-= 13;
        System.out.print(i1);
```

Comment: In my opinion it's easier to use the remainder operator `%` to simply add 13 and take the result mod 26. So something like `((i1 - 'a' + 13) % 26)+'a'` for lowercase and replace `'a'` with `'A'` for uppercase. By the way, the Character class has methods [`isLowerCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isLowerCase(char)) and `isUpperCase` to make this cleaner and less error-prone.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk `Character.isLowerCase('ă')` returns true.

Comment: @ﾓｷｬﾃﾞ: Good point, I guess there's no easy asciiLowerCase method. It's still probably cleaner to just first check if the character is <= 255 and then apply `isLowerCase`.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk `Character.isLowerCase('à')` is also true and `'à'` is 224.

Comment: @ﾓｷｬﾃﾞ: fail again, make it < 128.

Comment: thanks for all i used all suggestions but i couldnt manage to run it could you tell me another way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static String rot13(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0, length = s.length(); i < length; ++i) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            sb.append((char)((c - 'a' + 13) % 26 + 'a'));
        else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            sb.append((char)((c - 'A' + 13) % 26 + 'A'));
        else
            sb.append(c);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

and

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "How can you tell an extrovert from an\r\n"
        + "introvert at NSA? In the elevators,\r\n"
        + "the extroverts look at the OTHER guy's shoes.";
    String encoded = rot13(s);
    System.out.println("encoded:");
    System.out.println(encoded);
    String decoded = rot13(encoded);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("decoded:");
    System.out.println(decoded);
}
```

output:

```
encoded:
Ubj pna lbh gryy na rkgebireg sebz na
vagebireg ng AFN? Va gur ryringbef,
gur rkgebiregf ybbx ng gur BGURE thl'f fubrf.

decoded:
How can you tell an extrovert from an
introvert at NSA? In the elevators,
the extroverts look at the OTHER guy's shoes.
```

Comment: Thank you all i try all your suggestions and it worked!!